# How to configure HAProxy according request based on ports?

Tags: ssl, redirect, haproxy, high-availability

Here we are using haproxy for the redirection of HTTP to https, at backend we use the gateway. here gateway having already ssl certificate we redirected to it directly through HAProxy.

We have 2 URL one hit on port 80 and 2nd hit on port 8080 what are the possible conditions required for that have tried all possibilities. without using SSL it's working but regarding  to the SSL it can't  work it only work on 443 and its only applicable to the port 80 not getting assign to others.

Comment: our url was like that  www.example.com and www.example.com:8080